# Limits and pathological cases

Tags: limits

As we know, the definition of limit for a real valued function of one variable (I'll take $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) is:
$$\forall\epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 : x\in A , |x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$
Now, the definition is very clear in cases in which the function behaves nicely. Let's now take the example of a function defined this way: $f(x) = 1$ if $x \notin[-1,1]$, $f(x) = 1$ if $x=0$, not defined otherwise. If I take any $\epsilon >0$ a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-1|<\epsilon$ clearly exists. In fact, I could take any $\delta>1$ and every $x$ in the interval for which the function is defined the $\epsilon$ inequality would be satisfied, but it would somehow be silly to say that the limit as x approaches 0 is 1. It seems to me that the problem lies in that $x\in A$. Is something in my definition missing? Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: How can $|f(x) - 1| \lt \epsilon$ when $f(x)$ is not defined at all for $[-1, 1] \setminus \{0\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point $1$ is not an accumulation point of $A$. Taking limits in this case makes no sense at all. **Any** definition of $\lim_{x \to p} f(x)$ **must** begin with the words

> Let $p$ be an accumulation point of the domain of $f$.

Comment: And what if the function is defined only if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $p$ must be an accumulation point of the domain. Is it true or false?